# how to update the documents of nested array in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have different courses and multiple users can enroll in to it here i'm trying to update with the field `isChecked` in to true

this is the database:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("610035cb8e7acd3c68ca46fa"),
"is_free" : false,
"usersChecked" : [ 
    {
        "isChecked" : false,
        "userId" : "60f6fe96a1a44a1fb4a59573",
    }, 
    {
        "isChecked" : false,
        "userId" : "60f2990b8e0cc805b4245455",
    }
  ],
  }

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("610035cb8e7acd3c68c766fa"),
  "is_free" : false,
  "usersChecked" : [ 
    {
        "isChecked" : false,
        "userId" : "60f6fe96a1a43a1fb4a32573"
    }, 
    {
        "isChecked" : false,
        "userId" : "60f2990b8e0cc805b4245455"         
    }
]
}
```

Here `"userId" : "60f2990b8e0cc805b4245455"` is same for both the documents in the `usersChecked` and want to update the field `isChecked` to be true. i tried this way but the value is not updating .
please help me thanks in advance

this is the code:-

```
const usercourseExists = await Course.find({
   usersEnrolled: {
    $elemMatch: {
      userId: userid
    }
   }
})
 const listOfUsers = usercourseExists[0].usersEnrolled.map(function (el) {
    return el
  });
  let obj = listOfUsers.find(s => s.userId === req.body.userid);
  const userUpdated  =  await Course.updateMany({ "usersEnrolled.$.userId" : obj.userId }, {
    $addToSet: {
      usersChecked: {
        isChecked: true,
    }
  }})
```

Comment: What field `isChecked` do you want to update? All fields where `userId = 60f6fe96a1a43a1fb4a32573`? An specific field?

Comment: yes i want `isChecked` to be true when ever `userId` matches to `req.body.userid`

Comment: Can be the same `userId` in different arrays or will be only in one?

Comment: it will be in different arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `update()` query like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "usersChecked.userId": "60f2990b8e0cc805b4245455"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "usersChecked.$.isChecked": true
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

This query first find all documents where `userId` match and then do an update using [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update the matched values.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CBNhyq00C-o)

Also, if you are using mongoose, you can use `yourModel.updateMany(...)` and avoid `multi:true` stage.